# Machine Learning SVM contribution of features

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn, svm

I have used SKLearn SVM to be able to predict the label of new data (1 or 0). I used 60 features. Here is my code:

```
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf', gamma=0.001, C=1)  
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)  
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)   
print(clf.predict(X_test[:400]))
```

The next step I want to do is calculate the contribution of my features to the prediction, how do I do this?

And in addition I would like to plot the test and training error. Something like these figures from Ivan Ivanov..Hope anyone wants to help.

[image: Something like this]
[image: And something like this]

Comment: It's not possible to calculate the contribution of your features as you're using an rbf kernel. You will have to switch to a linear kernel and then look at the `coef_` attribute of your model.

Comment: Thank you ncfirth, I will switch to a linear kernel. Is it possible to calculate the second figure with the rbf kernel?

Comment: It's possible to make both the figures using the rbf kernel. The first figure you just have to train the model multiple times with a variable sized training set. The second figure is just a graphical representation of a confusion matrix, i.e. comparing true labels to predicted labels.